# Android phone MFA for Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-virtual-machine, multi-factor-authentication

How to use Andoid phone as virtual MFA device for Azure portal login prompt.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/multi-factor-authentication/multi-factor-authentication

I see, there is an option to use smart phone in that tutorial but not much on how to use it.

Also in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/multi-factor-authentication/end-user/microsoft-authenticator-app-how-to , can't find such options in azure dashboard

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you want to enable MFA for your Azure account and install APP on your Android phone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to enable MFA for your Azure account and install APP on your Android phone?

If I understand it correctly, we can login your Azure portal, and select **Multi-Factor Authentication**, like this screenshot:
[image]

More information about to **enable MFA for Azure AD account**, please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/multi-factor-authentication/multi-factor-authentication-get-started-cloud).

After MFA enabled, we should login https://myapps.microsoft.com, and select `profile` then select `Additional security verification`, like this:
[image]

In that page, you will find the configure settings:

[image]

After that, we can use this Microsoft Authenticator APP on your Android device.

**Update:**

### [image]

**Update2:**

If your first account is Microsoft account, we can't enable MFA in Azure portal, because Microsoft Account MFA different with Azure AD MFA. About Microsoft account MFA, we can follow this [article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/12408/microsoft-account-about-two-step-verification) to enable it.

Comment: Here, https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/usermanagement/multifactorverification.aspx , I can see the user but the MFA show disabled. How to enable..? After I select the user, I can't find the option to enable it

Comment: What does this mean.. Note: only users licensed to use Microsoft Online Services are eligible for Multi-Factor Authentication..? Is it possible to use MFA on free trial user..?

Comment: Also when I access https://myapps.microsoft.com , It redirects to https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/r and gets a white blank page... anything I am missing..?

Comment: we can enable MFA for free trial user, the limit is the user should create by this Azure AD, not a guest out of you Azure AD.   can you find the `quick steps` in that config page, on the right.

Comment: @LeoPrince Does this account is admin?

Comment: Yes I think. this one comes under Global Administrator

Comment: for test, could you please create another user in you Azure AD, and try to enable MFA for this account.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151696/discussion-between-leo-prince-and-jason-ye-msft).

Comment: @LeoPrince I have update my answer, please check it:)